# How to do a set union between two sets of different (but overlapping) sum types

Tags: ocaml

I am implementing the [generate First and Follow set algorithms](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/~cs331/notes/FirstFollow.pdf) for compilers.

Here is the type definition for First Set and Follow Set elements:

```
type first_set_element =
  | Terminal of terminal
  | Epsilon [@@deriving show, sexp]

type follow_set_element =
  | Terminal of terminal
  | EndSymbol [@@deriving show, sexp]
```

As you can see, the "Terminal" is the overlapping variant between the two.

I would like to be able to take a FollowSet and union with a FirstSet, then MINUS FirstSet's Epsilon, such that the result is still a FollowSet.

Of course, the "straightforward" solution is to write a function to convert the FirstSet to a FollowSet, then use `FollowSet.union`. Ideally, I would be able to NOT reimplement set operations. I am curious if there is something in the OCaml type system or perhaps a better design that addresses this.

Could [Polymorphic Variants](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2019sp/textbook/data/polymorphic_variants.html) be what I am looking for?

Here's how I define the Sets:

```
module FirstSetElement = struct
  type t = first_set_element
  let compare a b = match (a, b) with
    | (Terminal(a), Terminal(b)) -> String.compare a b
    | (Terminal(_), Epsilon) -> 1
    | (Epsilon, Terminal(_)) -> -1
    | (Epsilon, Epsilon) -> 0
  let sexp_of_t t = sexp_of_first_set_element t
  let t_of_sexp t = first_set_element_of_sexp t
end

module FirstSet = Set.Make(FirstSetElement)

module FollowSetElement = struct
  type t = follow_set_element
  let compare a b = match (a, b) with
    | (Terminal(a), Terminal(b)) -> String.compare a b
    | (Terminal(_), EndSymbol) -> 1
    | (EndSymbol, Terminal(_)) -> -1
    | (EndSymbol, EndSymbol) -> 0
  let sexp_of_t t = sexp_of_follow_set_element t
  let t_of_sexp t = follow_set_element_of_sexp t
end

module FollowSet = Set.Make(FollowSetElement)
```

Comment: Why are they different if their shape and behaviour is exactly the same? Is it just to provide a more meaningful name to the `Epsilon`/`EndSymbol` constructor? If so I'd say you should abstract the data structure away. Use a common data structure, but hide it and expose explicit constructor functions and operations instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, polymorphic variants help. They are exactly for such task.
Here's a simple example:

```ml
type a =
  [ `A
  | `Shared of int ]

type b =
  [ `B
  | `Shared of int ]

let a = [ `A; `Shared 1 ]
(* a :- [> `A | `Shared of int ] list *)

let b = [ `B; `Shared 2 ]
(* b :- [> `B | `Shared of int ] list *)

let c = a @ b
(* c :- [> `A | `B | `Shared of int ] list *)
```

You can read through the manual for more details.
The main drawback is you will get more verbose types, as shown above.